# React - Formatting image-box-wrappers to center

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

The `<div className="image-box-wrapper row justify-content-center">` on my portfolio component isn't laying out the portfolio pictures side by side. I can't seem to find the issue why they won't layout side by side. I think this would be the main piece of CSS that would affect this.

```
.portfolio-image {
  width: 15rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid var(--primary-green);
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

I checked the spelling and made sure the div was closed and still nothing. I'm still getting a column instead of side by side (horizontal). You can see the issue on my portfolio page at the link below. I appreciate help!

https://rinzler8806.github.io/reactPortfolio/

**Portfolio Component**

```
import React from "react";
import prw from "../images/prw.png";
import fitnesstracker from "../images/fitnesstracker.png";
import budgettracker from "../images/budgettracker.png";
import pangea from "../images/pangea.png";
//Font Awesome Imports
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faSearchPlus } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
//React POPUPBOX
import { PopupboxManager, PopupboxContainer } from "react-popupbox";
import "react-popupbox/dist/react-popupbox.css";

const Portfolio = () => {

  //Prow
  const openPopupboxProw = () => {
    const content = (
    <>
    <img className="portfolio-image-popupbox" src={prw} alt="prw"/>
    <p> Description of Popular Restaurants of the World
    As a traveler, I want to be able to search a location for surrounding restaurants so that I can find a local establishment to fit my needs.
<br></br>
<br></br>
      uses Foundation css framework
      application utilizes Zomato, and Google API's to retrieve restaurant data
      user can search restaurants around the world based on location and food type
      user searched cities are saved to local storage and can be accessed via the navbar
      when user inputs a location and food type the page will scroll to an embedded map with markers displaying local restaurants that meet search criteria
      when user clicks on map marker info about the restaurant will be displayed as well as a get directions link
    </p>
    <b>GitHub: </b> <a className="hyper-link" onClick={() => window.open("https://github.com/Rinzler8806/Popular-Restaurants-of-the-World-1")}>https://github.com/Rinzler8806/Popular-Restaurants-of-the-World-1</a>
    </>
    )
    PopupboxManager.open({content});
    PopupboxManager.update({
      content,
      config: {
        titleBar: {
          text: "Popular Restaurants of the World",
        },
      },
    });
  }

  const popupboxConfigProw = {
    titleBar: {
      enable: true,
      text: "Popular Restaurants of the World"
    },
    fadeIn: true,
    fadeInSpeed: 500
  }

  //fitnesstracker
  const openPopupboxFitnesstracker = () => {
    const content = (
    <>
    <img className="portfolio-image-popupbox" src={fitnesstracker} alt="fitnesstracker"/>
    <p>
<br></br>
<br></br>
This app has been created with the intention to be able to view create and track daily workouts. The user will be able to log multiple exercises in a workout on a given day. The user will also be able to track the name, type, weight, sets, reps, and duration of exercise. If the exercise is a cardio exercise, the user will be able to track their distance traveled.
    </p>
    <b>Demo: </b> <a className="hyper-link" onClick={() => window.open("https://infinite-beach-02354.herokuapp.com/exercise?id=6065391b3f573d0015bbd57e", "_blank")}>https://infinite-beach-02354.herokuapp.com/exercise?id=6065391b3f573d0015bbd57e</a>
    <br></br>
    <b>GitHub: </b> <a className="hyper-link" onClick={() => window.open("https://github.com/Rinzler8806/fitnessTracker")}>https://github.com/Rinzler8806/fitnessTracker</a>
    </>
    )
    PopupboxManager.open({content});
    PopupboxManager.update({
      content,
      config: {
        titleBar: {
          text: "Fitness Tracker",
        },
      },
    });
  }

  const popupboxConfigFitnesstracker = {
    titleBar: {
      enable: true,
      text: "Fitness Tracker"
    },
    fadeIn: true,
    fadeInSpeed: 500
  }

   //budgettracker
   const openPopupboxBudgettracker = () => {
    const content = (
    <>
    <img className="portfolio-image-popupbox" src={budgettracker} alt="budgettracker"/>
    <p>
<br></br>
<br></br>
The user will be able to add expenses and deposits to their budget with or without a connection. When entering transactions offline, they should populate the total when brought back online.
<br></br>
Offline Functionality:
Enter deposits offline.
Enter expenses offline.
<br></br>
When brought back online:
Offline entries should be added to tracker.
    </p>
    <b>Demo: </b> <a className="hyper-link" onClick={() => window.open("https://fathomless-sea-54648.herokuapp.com/", "_blank")}>https://fathomless-sea-54648.herokuapp.com/</a>
    <br></br>
    <b>GitHub: </b> <a className="hyper-link" onClick={() => window.open("https://github.com/Rinzler8806/BudgetTracker")}>https://github.com/Rinzler8806/BudgetTracker</a>
    </>
    )
    PopupboxManager.open({content});
    PopupboxManager.update({
      content,
      config: {
        titleBar: {
          text: "Budget Tracker",
        },
      },
    });
  }

  const popupboxConfigBudgettracker = {
    titleBar: {
      enable: true,
      text: "Budget Tracker"
    },
    fadeIn: true,
    fadeInSpeed: 500
  }

     //Pangea
     const openPopupboxPangea = () => {
      const content = (
      <>
      <img className="portfolio-image-popupbox" src={pangea} alt="Pangea"/>
      <p> Pangea
  <br></br>
  <br></br>
  A dynamic messaging application that connects users around the globe. It offers many features and the ability to actively translate your message to a selected language.
  <br></br>
  Log in as: Batman and use password: password to view demo.
      </p>
      <b>Demo: </b> <a className="hyper-link" onClick={() => window.open("https://pangeachat.herokuapp.com/", "_blank")}>https://pangeachat.herokuapp.com/</a>
      <br></br>
      <b>GitHub: </b> <a className="hyper-link" onClick={() => window.open("https://github.com/Rinzler8806/pangea-chat")}>https://github.com/Rinzler8806/pangea-chat</a>
      </>
      )
      PopupboxManager.open({content});
      PopupboxManager.update({
        content,
        config: {
          titleBar: {
            text: "Pangea",
          },
        },
      });
    }
  
    const popupboxConfigPangea = {
      titleBar: {
        enable: true,
        text: "Pangea"
      },
      fadeIn: true,
      fadeInSpeed: 500
    }



  return (
    <div id="Portfolio" className="portfolio-wrapper">
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="text-uppercase text-center py-5">Portfolio</h1>
        <div Classname="image-box-wrapper row justify-content-center">
          <div Classname="portfolio-image-box" onClick={openPopupboxProw}>
          <img className="portfolio-image" src={prw} alt="prw" />
          <div className="overflow"></div>
          <FontAwesomeIcon className="portfolio-icon" icon={faSearchPlus} />
        </div>
        {/* - */}
        <div Classname="portfolio-image-box" onClick={openPopupboxFitnesstracker}>
          <img className="portfolio-image" src={fitnesstracker} alt="fitnesstracker" />
          <div className="overflow"></div>
          <FontAwesomeIcon className="portfolio-icon" icon={faSearchPlus} />
        </div>
        {/* - */}
        <div Classname="portfolio-image-box" onClick={openPopupboxBudgettracker}>
          <img className="portfolio-image" src={budgettracker} alt="budgettracker" />
          <div className="overflow"></div>
          <FontAwesomeIcon className="portfolio-icon" icon={faSearchPlus} />
        </div>
        {/* - */}
        <div Classname="portfolio-image-box" onClick={openPopupboxPangea}>
          <img className="portfolio-image" src={pangea} alt="pangea" />
          <div className="overflow"></div>
          <FontAwesomeIcon className="portfolio-icon" icon={faSearchPlus} />
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <PopupboxContainer {...popupboxConfigProw} />
        <PopupboxContainer {...popupboxConfigFitnesstracker} />
        <PopupboxContainer {...popupboxConfigBudgettracker} />
        <PopupboxContainer {...popupboxConfigPangea} />
        </div> 
  )
}

export default Portfolio;
```

**CSS**

```
.portfolio-wrapper {
  background: var(--primary-light-grey);
  padding: 3rem 0;
}

.portfolio-wrapper h1 {
  color: var(--primary-green);
}

.portfolio-image {
  width: 15rem;
  border: 1px solid var(--primary-green);
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

.portfolio-image-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.popupbox-wrapper {
  margin-top: 7rem;
}

/*OVERFLOW BOX*/

.overflow {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  background: var(--primary-black);
  width: 15rem;
  height: 8rem;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid var(--primary-purple);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-image-box:hover .overflow {
  opacity: 60%;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.portfolio-icon {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: -8rem;
  margin-top: 3.6rem;
  color: var(--primary-purple);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.portfolio-image-box:hover .portfolio-icon {
  opacity: 70%;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*POPUPBOX*/
.portfolio-image-popupbox {
  width: 45rem;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.hyper-link {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--primary-blue);
}

.hyper-link:hover {
  color: var(--primary-purple);
}

/*MEDIA*/

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .portfolio-image-popupbox {
    width: 100%;
}
}

@media(max-height: 570px) {
.popupbox-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

  .portfolio-image-popupbox {
    width: 50%;
}
}

@media(max-height: 570px) {
  .popupbox-content {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
    .portfolio-image-popupbox {
      width: 100%;
  }
  }

  @media(max-height: 280px) {
    .popupbox-wrapper {
      height: 90%;
    }
    
      .portfolio-image-popupbox {
        width: 30%;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you seems to have missed the implementations of your `image-box-wrapper`, `row`
and `justify-content-center` classes.

That is why no styling is being applied to the container.

Adding a simple `display: flex` in chrome dev tools solved the issue.

[image: Check this out]

Comment: Perhaps I am doing something wrong. When I add the styling for display: flex there is no change. I did add this to .portfolio-image {display: flex} and it centered the boxes vertically stacked one on top of the other. However, I am wanting them to appear as they do in your screenshot.

I also tried adding styling specifically for the image-box-wrapper and there is no change. .image-box-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

Any further insight to this newbie would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Try to directly add a style prop on the parent container and set `display: 'flex'` as the inline style. If that works, it means that there is something wrong with your classes. Since they are not getting bundled correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help Nisanth! I just noticed that I had "className" spelled out as "Classname". Once I changed this everything fell into place correctly! Thank you again :)

Comment: Glad to help :)